# Android | Syntax Error in regexp pattern

Tags: java, android, regex

I am using `\\.(.*)}` regex pattern to search a specific string in my Android Test Project. when i am using this regex to check on online available tools the regex looks fine. but in Android Test Project I am getting this following error.

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 7:
\.(.*)}
^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:400)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:383)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:367)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you post the string for which you are using it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try escaping your `}`: -

```
"\\.(.*)\\}"  // escaping `}` not needed in Java
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work in `android`, but in `Java` it works fine `without escaping` it.

However, if you are using an *opening curly braces*, then even in Java you would need to escape it: -

```
"\\.(.*)\\{"  // escaping `{` needed even in Java
```

Comment: i needed to use both open and closed curly brackets and i had to put escapes for both..

Comment: @g.revolution.. Actually, didn't knew that it works that way in Android.

Comment: thanx for the answer though .. @Nikita mentioned your answer was first :D .. so selecting yours as correct one.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45075252/1573036) answer explains why it does not work in Android.

Answer (score 8):

You need to escape `}` as @Rohit Jain said:

```
String regex = "\\.(.*)\\}";
```

Your regex does work in java, but it fails on android for some reason.

Comment: yups .. got it worked .. i escaped } also and it worked .. i did it before reading the answer though :D but i'll still accept this in 8 minutes :-p

Comment: i saw yours first.. and i refreshed also as you mentioned @rohit .. but rohit's answer was not not being shown to me .. it is now .. i have accepted his.. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I just surround it with a

```
 try{

 }catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and it worked.