# Regex pattern error in Android when matching closing brace

Tags: java, android, regex

I am using java.util.regex.Pattern class to match a string in a Android program.

```
if(Pattern.matches("\\{\\{.*?}}", element.getValue())) {
   ...             
} else {
   ...
}
```

And I got the following error.

```
 Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 8
                                                                  \{\{.*?}}
```

I am using Android studio and Open JDK. To test the regex expression I wrote a simple program in Netbeans and it works fine. Netbeans also use openjdk.

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("\\{\\{.*?}}", "{{hello:sdf}}"));
```

Why the regular expression is giving an error in android project?

Comment: I think you just need to use `if (element.getValue().matches("\\{\\{.*?}}"))`,  try also escaping `}`s if you still have issues.

Comment: I have noticed on pre api version 21 `java.util.regex` matcher does not work correctly. It is better to rather use `com.google.code.regexp`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
"\\{\\{.*?\\}\\}"
```

The issue is that the regex engine used in Android is an [ICU engine](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) that is different from Java one, and **both** `{` and `}` that represent literal open/close curly braces must be escaped in ICU regex patterns.

In the overwhelming majority of regex flavors `}` does not have to be escaped, but it is not the case with the ICU regex engine that cannot deduce the `}` meaning based on the pattern context. E.g. PCRE, .NET, Python, Java regexes find `}` in `[a-z]}` pattern and as there is no `{` before, they "know" it is not a part of the [limiting quantifier construct](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit). ICU is not that smart. It still thinks there must be a `{` that is followed with digit(s) before `}` and reports an error if it is unescaped.